# Conveying "let's agree to disagree"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

What are some common ways to convey in French: "*Let's agree to disagree*"?
Is

> Disons qu'on est pas d'accord

idiomatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disons qu'on **n'** est pas d'accord* est une bonne traduction oui. D'autres possibilités (un peu plus formelles) :

> - Accordons-nous sur notre désaccord.
> - Soyons d'accord dans notre désaccord.
> - Acceptons notre désaccord.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I omitted on purpose 'n' from n'est pas for sounding more native I thought:-)!

Comment: Okay, then you're an one level up from me ;) You're right, it's more native-alike to omit the n in informal texts (texto, letters) it's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment. In speech as well:-)! I've heard even university professors systematically omitting 'n' even in less relaxed settings (meetings, lectures and the like).

Comment: Actually, you can't omit the n in a speech as it sounds the same with or without (with the *liaison*). Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. It sounds the same. So let me change it to '*Disons que nous sommes pas d'accord*':-)!

Comment: @Dimitris That doesn't work well. ***Nous*** is formal so leads to using ***ne***.

Comment: — Premier résultat de DeepL (https://www.deepl.com/translator#en/fr/Let's%20agree%20to%20disagree) : « Soyons d'accord *sur* notre désaccord » j’ai cliqué sur le *sur* et n’est pas trouvé *dans* … avec les autres mots proposés on peut combiner moult belles phrases :-)